# Trying to upgrade to 20.04.1

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

I'm trying to upgrade to 20.04.1 but i'm running into problems.

This is my console:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1 554 B]                                         
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1 342 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1 344 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'focal.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Get:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease [64,4 kB]      
Hit https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                
Hit https://repos.influxdata.com/debian stretch InRelease                      
Hit https://repo.steampowered.com/steam beta InRelease                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                          
Hit https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public InRelease                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                
Fetched 64,4 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                  
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Checking for installed snaps

Calculating snap size requirements

Updating repository information

Third party sources disabled 

Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can 
re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool 
or your package manager. 

To continue please press [ENTER]

Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                 
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This was likely caused by: 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and 
try the upgrade again. 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If 
you want to investigate this yourself the log files in 
'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. 
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

Tried installing ppa-purge but that shows up as not found.

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ppa-purge
```

What do i do now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: What is the current Ubuntu version. I bet it is EoL.

Comment: Current version is Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: Not sure what Universe repository is.

Comment: Steam, Influx, and Plex are your three biggest problems.  Those are third party packages NOT maintained in the Ubuntu repositories and it can't upgrade if there's conflicting libraries installed by those that conflict with the main repositories.  Chances are you already have Universe enabled, but you have third party packages that can't be installed/upgraded in place.  Either remove the packages completely, or backup your data to secondary media and then do a clean installation of 20.04 and then restore your data from the backups.

Comment: @ThomasWard
When you say remove packages you mean uninstall the programs completely or just remove the sources?

Answer (score 0):

Turning on Universe and then updating there actually allowed me to install the update!